# Horizontal Ripple Text

Tags: text, photoshop-effects, effects, illustrator-effects

How do I create this text ripple effect in Illustrator or Photoshop? I'm able to add a wave effect, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Is there anything specific you need help with on this? Why don't you like the wave effect you created?

Answer (score 2):

In Ai do an envelope distort with mesh. Push between the mesh nodes or select a row of nodes

Answer (score 0):

- Select T to add a text
- Rasterize the text by right click on the layer > Rasterize
- go to Photoshop menu bar > Window > Liquefy and with the first option on the top left corner selected, adjust the size of the brush and the pressure